# jQuery count the number of class names WITHIN an element

Tags: jquery, html, class, select

I'm currently working on creating a custom select menu and one of the stumbling blocks I have hit is the transition of classes between the default select element and the new one. One method i have tried is..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        var class = "select";

        if ($(this).attr("class").length > 0) {
            class = class + " " + $(this).attr("class");
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, all it is doing is measuring the amount of characters found rather than the amount of instances found. It's probably one of the easiest things to do but I just can't seem to get my head around it. Anybody have any ideas as to what I can do?

I would just like to point out, it **DOESN'T** matter what the class names are, because it could be absolutely any name, it is simply so if i have for example one custom select i want to float to the right, i simply write `<select class="right"></select>` and the `class=right` would then be noted by the script and moved over to the new select.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var classNames = [];
    $("select").each(function () {
        var classes = (this.className || '').split(/\s+/);
        $.each(classes, function (i, v) {
            if ($.inArray(v, classNames) == -1) {
                classNames.push(v)
            }
        })
    });
    console.log(classNames)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FWS6x/)

Comment: Time to learn some new jQuery functions! This looks rather helpful i'll have a look..

Answer (score 1):

The word `class` is a reserved word. Change it to something else, like `classname` and it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        var classname = "select";

        if ($(this).attr("class").length > 0) {
            classname = classname + " " + $(this).attr("class");
        }
        console.log(classname);
    });
});
```

Comment: That explains it then! Note to self; create unique variables! Cheers :)